# Set whatsapp to send delayed messages?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Is there any extention or function to manage whatsapp to send delayed messages?

I would like to send every day a message at the same time but I do not find this function?

The message is different every day and there are images or text

Comment: Check this app, it should do if your device is rooted (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.seebye.whatsapp.scheduler).

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.seebye.whatsapp.scheduler) called `Seebye Scheduler ROOT` which can do what you intend but the device must be ROOTED and [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.seebye.scheduler) one named `Scheduler NO ROOT`(from the same developer) is also available, for non-rooted device.

Once app is installed on your device, user needs to set a rule, by below steps,

 1. setting the user to whom the message will be sent,
 2. message text that needs to be sent, 
3. when it needs to be sent  
4.how frequently it needs to be sent.

None of my devices are compatible with these app, hence I could not test it myself, but looks worth for trying! Good Luck.

Answer (score -1):

Sending automated texts is possible. "Tasker" is a powerful app that lets you do so.. It could be complicated to use at start. So I would recommend you search on youtube about the same using Tasker app.

Comment: You're beating the bushes. I can write 10s of answers saying that Tasker can do this, it's a powerful app and whatnot. However, the answers here are supposed to be detailed and to the point. So please, write a detailed answer explaining how to use Tasker to achieve the goal in question. Read [How do I write a good answer?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Not even a link to the app, nor a statement "I used and it works" - - - "powerful app" sounds like marketing... But instead sending us to search on YouTube :(